# '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': no such file or directory

Tags: upgrade, qt-creator

Hello I have problem when i want to install qt creator in ubuntu using raspberry pi. the problem say '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': no such file or directory. can someone help me with this.

Comment: Please provide OS & release details (which product are you using?)  for best results though you should provide the full command & messages that show the problem... We currently don't know if you're asking about a Core product (*yy* format) or standard release (*yy.mm* format)

Comment: the os i'm using is ubuntu desktop 21.04 (64bit) and my raspberry pi 4 model B- 8Gb.

Comment: **How** are you trying to install qt creator? it looks like you may be trying to install the wrong architecture

Comment: I download the qt creator software from the websits (https://www.qt.io/download). when i wanted to run the software using terminal it give this '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': no such file or directory error